# What does "What's more...I never have." mean?

Tags: meaning

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), a plaintiff attorney, Rohr confronts Ranking Fitch, a jury consultant
of the defendants, the gun manufacturers :

> Rohr: You're gonna lose. Well, maybe not this case, maybe not the
> next, but someday. You know, someday. I've seen it before with guys
> like you. You wanna know why? Because you cannot carry that much
> contempt without it becoming malignant. Until you'll be all alone in a
> room full of shadows...and all you're gonna have is the memories of
> all those lives you have destroyed.
>
> Rankin Fitch: Well, that's a good story, Wendall. But it's just
> further proof of why you can't beat me. Because you may be right...but
> the thing of it is, I don't give a shit. **What's more... I never have**.

What does "What's more...I never have." mean?

Comment: Here is a good dictionary definition of the phrase "what's more": https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/what-s-more

Comment: by the way, the character's name is "Rankin" a not unheard of first name in the US, not "Ranking" which would be quite unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I don't give a shit. What's more... I never have."

"What's more" says that the speaker is providing more information. "I never have" refers back to "give a shit".  The speaker has never given a shit.

The whole sentence provides emphasis. Fitch is saying that he doesn't give a shit.  But what is even more impressive is that he "never" gave a shit.